# Logical OR Operator Returns False

Tags: java, api

Why does this return a false?

```
if (!member.getPermissions().contains(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR) || !member.getId().equals(UniversalVariables.DJZK)) {
            eb = EmbedMaker.embedBuilderDescription(MessageSender.noPermission);
            channel.sendMessage(eb.build()).queue();
            return;
}
```

Comment: Please provides us bigger code snippet to have an idea what values can be in your if condition

Comment: It would return false if the member is an admin with ID of djzk. Are you asking how Boolean logic works? It’s not clear what result you want.

Comment: @NathanHughes that's my problem.  What i want to do is, "If member (doer of command) doesnt have an admin permission, OR doesnt have my ID then send no permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be a bit more specifi CH as far as i can tell you say in the if-Statement:

> if you have NOT permission ADMINISTRATOR OR Are NOT user A then Do smoething

This is logically equivalent to if you are both ADMINISTRATOR AND user A then DON‘T run the if statement.

So you probably are the said user A and have the said permission.

Comment: it's supposed to be a block. That will keep normal users from using the command.

What i want to do is, ` if member is not an admin or if member is not this user (which is me ) then send no permission`

Comment: @DJZK: You don’t want OR, you want AND. If member is not an admin and member isn’t you then no permission. Or use de Morgan’s rule:  if (not (admin or me)).

Comment: @NathanHughes but i need atleast 1 false to both of statements for it to be true. That's why if im the doer of command, it works. but if other admins it does not

Comment: i need this answer from other way. Because im doing a negative approach block. @NathanHughes your Morgan's rule worked

Comment: @DJZK: cool. They come in handy. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Answer (score 0):

your return; statement has no argument so it returns "nothing"! This may be 0 which is interpreted as False.
So the logic *or* is irrelevant to the return value. So *return(true);* would return logic true when the if condition is true.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be a block for the code from proceeding

Comment: Do you actually ask: Is the if() statement's true condition executed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Nathan's Answer was right. Usage of Morgan's Rule. [image]

```
if(!(member.getPermissions().contains(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR) || member.getId().equals(UniversalVariables.DJZK))){
            eb = EmbedMaker.embedBuilderDescription(MessageSender.noPermission);
            channel.sendMessage(eb.build()).queue();
            return;
}
```

Comment: Props to @NathanHughes